# Shelves for super computing cluster

Tags: cluster, rack, supercomputer

So I am currently running a small project with a few friends and we require a 2 Teraflop super computing cluster we have gathered all the money for this project mainly from donations and we need to know where we would find racks similar to the one in the link below?

http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/cluster-640x480.jpg

Comment: Hi Bartel - shopping recommendations are off topic per the FAQ.  Please take the time to read it - thank you.

Comment: Those look like regular kitchen shelves to me.  Found just about anywhere (here's a 4-shelf version: http://www.amazon.com/Alera-Complete-Wire-Shelving-Casters/dp/B005SG1FE6)

Comment: This is not a "what should I buy" question. It's a "where can I find" question, which we do all the time.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of shelving (not really a rack) is ubuiquitous, and with good reason: sturdy, easy to put together. If you peek into a restaurnt kitchen, you'll probably see some sheving like this. The cool thing is that it uses its own weight to keep the shelves in place.

This shelving is sold by most big-box stores under a variety of names. They're easy to spot because the posts have a lot of horizontal grooves that catch the sleeves that hold the shelves up.

If you want a specific source, there's Metro Commercial. Their consumer line is mainly sold through [Container Store](http://www.containerstore.com/shop/shelving/metroregCommercial).